# Bind container port to host inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, binding, port, dockerfile

Normally when binding port, I would do `docker run -p hostport:dockerport ...`, but can I specify the port binding inside my `Dockerfile` ?

I'm starting a server that listens on a port. The server takes the port through cmd line arguments. It would be great if I don't have to repeat the port in two places (in `docker run` command and in `Dockerfile`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `dockerfile` you can only use `expose`. The `EXPOSE` instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime. EXPOSE does not make the ports of the container accessible to the host.

To allocate Hostport to container you need to do `publish` (`-p`). Or the `-P` flag to publish **all** of the exposed ports.

To automate the process, You can use `docker-compose`. In docker compose file you can orchestrate multiple `docker run` commands with different arguments.

Comment: ah yes I should look at docker-compose. Thanks!

Comment: But it does not work when we create a container after image creation