# Cannot connect to exposed port of container started with docker-compose on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having trouble accessing apps that should expose ports to the host via docker-compose. Here is a reproducible example:

I create a new angular app using the angular CLI:

```
ng new angular-docker
```

Then I create a Dockerfile with the following contents in that directory:

```
FROM node:8

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Next I create a docker-compose.yaml file in the same directory:

```
version: '3'

services:
  angular:
    build: .
    container_name: angular-docker
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

Then I run:

```
docker-compose up
```

I wait until I get the following line in the docker-compose output

```
angular-docker | ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

From `docker inspect angular-docker` I see that the port-forwarding rule is in place:

```
...
"Ports": {
            "4200/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "4200"
                }
            ]
        },
...
```

Now, when I try to go to http://localhost:4200 in Chrome, I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

However, when I use `docker exec -it angular-docker bash` to bash into the container, I get a response, when I `curl localhost:4200`.

**My environment:**

- OS: Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299
- Docker: 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513)

I figured that this might be a firewall issue. So for debugging, I closed the firewall application (I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security), with no luck.

Why can I not access the container from the exposed port?

EDIT:

`netstat -an | findstr ":4200"` returns the following:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:4200           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::1]:4200             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind container port to host inside Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552034/bind-container-port-to-host-inside-dockerfile)

Comment: Have you checked if your server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200 or localhost:4200?

Comment: @Cyclops see my edit

Comment: @Nima I wanted to confirm if that netstat was from host or from inside of docker container. Because on host, docker proxy binds 0.0.0.0:4200 as well as localhost:4200. Anyway, juan's answer and your acceptance towards his answer confirms my suspicion that your server was not listening on 0.0.0.0:4200

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use the default `npm start` out of the box within a docker container.

One alternative is to update that command in your `package.json` to run `ng serve -H 0.0.0.0` like this:

`"start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0"`

This extra `-H 0.0.0.0` is to listen to all the interfaces from the container.

Then as your port mappings are working, you should get your site on the desired port `localhost:4200` from the host machine.

Comment: Thank you @Juan, that was it. For future readers: In version 6.x of Angular CLI, the shorthand `-H` was dropped, so you have to use `--host`

Comment: Why is this answer only up voted 5 times. It's not that obvious to think off this

Comment: @CrazyGreenHand 

Answer (score 2):

Would you please check http://127.0.0.1:4200

On a lot of Linux servers I bump into the problem that "localhost" resolves into "::1" being ipv6 while the application is only configured to listen on ipv4 addresses. Double-checking with "127.0.0.1" can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

When you use EXPOSE in docker, the port stay available to tcp connections wit others containers in your docker network. If you want to be able to connect a port using http, you should map ports from your local machine to a container port.

```
PORTS
 -3000:3000
```

Where the first port is the port on your local machine an the second ṕort is on the container.

Comment: If you look at the docker-compose.yaml, I have set the ports configuration option to "4200:4200". Removing the `EXPOSE 4200` in the Dockerfile, didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this

```
services: 
 application:
   container_name: angular-docker
   image: Your_image_build_from_docker_file
   ports:
    - "4200:4200"
   volumes:
    - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
```